# What does "It's working time from here." mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, error

> Person A: For several days I am not able to open Internet Archive
>   http://www.archive.org. Is the site closed now?
>
> Person B: I use it every day and just checked, ***It's working time from
>   here.*** ([Source](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/Parthia-L/conversations/messages/6281))[image]

What is intention of B by saying "It's working time from here."?

Comment: If it was my friend, I would've said: *Well, what do you guess?* But you aren't my friend.......You're my pal. ;) Well, as a serious note, it seems not to be [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_time). Though I guess more context should be there for one to make sure.

Comment: Seems like it should be "It's working **fine** from here." Any possibility it was misunderstood?

Comment: Looks more like a typo to me too. "It's English, Jim, but not as we know it."

Comment: I have added the link of conversation.

Comment: I don't have a Yahoo account, can't check it.

Comment: Its image has added.

Comment: Typo, possibly "supported" by some auto-correct function, like "fime" ('n' is next to 'm' on a keyboard) -> "time"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typographical error. Person B almost certainly meant to say:

> It's working **fine** from here.

In this context, "from here" means "as seen from my computer". In other words, person B means that he just checked the Internet Archive, and it worked fine on person B's computer. So, either the problems that person A experienced were temporary and have stopped now, or those problems are due to something other than the Internet Archive being closed. Perhaps a router or other computer on the Internet, which normally would transmit information from the Internet Archive to Person A, is not working.

As Stephie pointed out, *m* and *n* are near each other on a typical keyboard (and *f* and *t* are near each other, too), so a typographical error seems likely. Autocorrect may have "corrected" *fime* to *time* instead of *fine.*